# airflow blocking threads machine learning end to end

Tags: machine-learning, concurrency, io, airflow, blocking

I am running airflow for end to end machine learning, and some machine learning tasks take hours to train. I do not want the dags and corresponding train tasks to be the bottle neck, how would I allow for multiple tasks to be scheduled ? I'm assuming I'd have to change my executor from Sequential to Celery. Is there anything else I'd be missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Besides Celery, you can also use LocalExecutor, which is more simple to setup and may fit your needs. Furthermore, you can create a pool for machine learning tasks, while using the default pool for the rest of tasks
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=pool#pools